# Jquery nth-child fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors

I have problem with javascript and HTML. I want to pop out a message if value of text input is wrong.

```
    $('input[name="login"]').blur(function() {
    $('.error:nth-child(2)').fadeIn('fast', function() {

    });
});
```

and HTML/PHP code:

```
    echo "<div class=\"grid_2 alpha\">Nazwa użytkownika</div><div class=\"grid_2 omega register\">".form_input('login', set_value('login', ''))."</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"error grid_4\">Niepoprawna nazwa użytkownika.</div>";
```

What I cannot achieve is to actually fadeIn this little div. Nothing happens. 
What can be wrong with this code?

Everything works when I'm not using :nth-child().

Comment: Can you post your HTML? Also, are you getting any errors?

Comment: please show relevant html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to be sure without seeing more code, but I have a feeling what you're after is something like:

```
$(".error").eq(2).fadeIn("fast", function() {
    //Done!
});
```

`eq` will only match elements of the specified selector, whereas `nth-child` will look at all siblings. Therefore, the above code will select the 2nd element matching `.error`. You can also use the `:eq` pseudo-selector if you prefer:

```
$(".error:eq(2)").fadeIn("fast", function() {});
```

The difference between `eq` and `nth-child` is a common source of confusion. The [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) help clear it up:

> The :nth-child(n) pseudo-class is easily confused with :eq(n), even
>   though the two can result in dramatically different matched elements.
>   With :nth-child(n), all children are counted, regardless of what they
>   are, and the specified element is selected only if it matches the
>   selector attached to the pseudo-class. With :eq(n) only the selector
>   attached to the pseudo-class is counted, not limited to children of
>   any other element, and the (n+1)th one (n is 0-based) is selected.

*Of course, I may be completely wrong and when you post more code I may well have to delete this answer!*

Comment: Ahh thought so :) Glad I could help!